# Django+Celery не выполняется task

Tags: python, django, redirect, celery

Я хочу сделал так что при регистрации пользователя к нему на почту приходило сообщение для подтверждение почты, я подключил Celery(Redis). Но почему то сообщение на почту не отправляется, вот мой код:

tasks.py:

```
@shared_task
def send_email_verification(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    expiration = now() + timedelta(hours=48)
    record = EmailVerification.objects.create(code=uuid.uuid4(), user=user, expiration=expiration)
    record.send_verification_email()
```

Теперь метод save в форме регистрации, forms.py:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=True)
    send_email_verification.delay(user.id)
    return user
```

Получается что при регистрации, должно отправится сообщение на почту, но загвоздка в том что никаких ошибок нет, но сообщение на почту не прихоит. Допустим в коде у меня написано вот так:

```
send_email_verification.delay(user.id)
```

Я пытался самостоятельно решить проблему, и попытался отредактировать код, и я попробовал здесь убрать delay и написать как:

```
send_email_verification(user.id)
```

Весь код отработает но уже как вы сами понимаете не параллельно, пожалуйста помогите решить проблему! Я подключал Celery по документации, в settings.py есть конфигурация:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
```

А также вот логи:

```
[2023-05-28 02:12:09,755: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process 1652 calling self.run()
[2023-05-28 02:15:15,970: INFO/MainProcess] Task users.tasks.send_email_verification[35724a89-f4da-448d-8000-81bdca5a7689] received
[2023-05-28 02:15:17,407: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-18] child process 1048 calling self.run()
```

Он как бы видит, получает task, но не выполняет его. Прошу помочь, если знаете!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне с такой проблемой помогла библиотека `eventlet`:

```
pip install eventlet
```

Затем нужно добавить в запуске:

```
celery -A <project_name> worker --loglevel=info -P eventlet
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помог! Но хотелось бы узнать почему так происходит. Почему если я запускаю вот так: `celery -A <project_name> worker --loglevel=info` не работает, а если запускаю как ты показывал: `celery -A <project_name> worker --loglevel=info -P eventlet` то все работает.

Comment: Не за что, если ответ был полезным можно, поставить стрелочку вверх, а если помог, то галочку. А на счет почему не работает, можно почитать вот [здесь](https://distributedpython.com/posts/two-ways-to-make-celery-4-run-on-windows/) и [здесь](https://distributedpython.com/posts/celery-execution-pools-what-is-it-all-about/), если вкратце, как я понял, `celery worker` не выполняет задачи, а создает `pool` процессов (потоков), который эти задачи выполняет, и как раз `eventlet` один из способов создания `pool-a`.